# Scala Xml Parsing: How to get Node with a attribute excluding subnode

Tags: xml, scala, scala-xml

I have a xml as follows:

```
<Head>
  <Company>
   <Props>

   </Props>
   <Config>

    </Config>
        <Products>
            <Product type="Random" name="xyz">
                <Property name="asd" value="asd"/>
            </Product>
            <Product type="Random1" name="xyz1">
                <Property name="asd1" value="asd1"/>
            </Product>
            <Product type="Random2" name="xyz">
                <Property name="asd2" value="asd2"/>
            </Product>
         </Products>
   </Company>
</Head>
```

I need to extract node "Product" and its attribute "name". But (Subnode of "Product") "Property" also has attribute "name". 
I wrote a code as follows:

```
val xml = XML.loadFile("product.xml")

val names = (Head \\ Company \\ prodcuts \\ product \\ "@name").map { _.text }
```

But this returns a list of name of product and property both. 
How do i select only Product names ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do smth like that:

```
( xml \\ "Product").map( n => n \@ "name").foreach(println)
```

Using double backslash `\\` means that you want to select all sequence elements and all it subsequence's. 
You can use single backslash `\` to chose only sequence element. But it works only if you have one child element but not a list.

My solution is to iterate through all `Product` elements and pick up relevant sequence attribute of it.